# What is the common $t$-test for $H_0: \mu = \mu_0 \ \text{ and } \ H_A:\mu > \mu_0$?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

The following remark came up in my lecture:

> Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be normally distributed with known variance $\sigma^2 > 0$.
>
> For testing
>
> $$H_0: \mu = \mu_0 \ \text{ and } \ H_A:\mu > \mu_0.$$
>
> we use the "common level-$\alpha$-test". (If I am not mistaken my teachter meant the $t$-test with this.)

In the lecture we only did tests where the alternative hypothesis was the complement of the hypothesis, so I do not understand what the "common level-$\alpha$-test" is supposed to be. Could you please explain this to me?

To clearify: My problem here is that I do not understand how to formulate a test where $H_A$ is not complementary to $H_0$.

Comment: If the variance $\sigma^2$ is known, the common test to use here is the one-sided z-test, which is uniformly most powerful (UMP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct; technically speaking, the null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis are complementary, i.e. they specify regions that are mutually exclusive and collectively exhaust the parameter space (i.e. they *partition* the space).

The reason you may see the *composite* null hypothesis in a one-sided test $H_0: \mu\leq \mu_0$ replaced with a *simple* null hypothesis $H_0: \mu=\mu_0$ has to do with how we conduct tests. The aim is to control the *size* of the test, which is the supremum of the type 1 error over all data generating processes satisfying the null hypothesis:

$$\sup_{h \in H_0}P(\text{reject } H_0|h)\leq \alpha.$$

That is, we want to ensure the "worst case" type 1 error is below cutoff $\alpha$. For the composite null $H_0: \mu\leq \mu_0$, the worst case type 1 error corresponds with $\mu=\mu_0.$ Visually you can see this by drawing any other normal curve with mean $\mu<\mu_0$ and noting that the probability of rejecting the null (right tail area above some cutoff) is lower than in the case $\mu=\mu_0$.

In summary, it is without loss to replace $H_0:\mu\leq \mu_0$ with $H_0:\mu=\mu_0$ in a one-sided t test; just treat them the same and carry on.

Comment: I am not sure about your first paragraph. I would have thought you could quite easily have $H_0: X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $H_1: X \sim N(10,\sigma^2)$ for unknown $\sigma^2$ and then test $H_0$.  This lets you decide what counts as an extreme observation when testing the null hypothesis, while letting you ignore other issues such as  the possibility the distribution is not normal.  Indeed simple alternative hypotheses also allow power analysis.  Since the alternative hypothesis may also be wrong, many people reject or fail to reject the null hypothesis but do not accept either hypothesis

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the comment. Are you referring to the point that $H_0,H_1$ partition the parameter space? I would argue in your example that the parameter space is $\{0,10\}\times\mathbb{R}_+$.